# issues with sending php variable to another page

Tags: php, session, variables, cookies, xampp

Is there any other way of sending variables from one page to another without using `get`, `post`, cookie, or `session`?

I'm using header redirect, so I can't use `get` or `post` and I'm not able to set cookie, so I can't use `setcookie`. session is working, but I don't want to use `session` for some other reasons.

Is there any other way to send variables?

Comment: You can use `get` method for header redirect. If you don't want to use any of above option store that value in db.

Comment: you can keep your data in xml format too

Comment: @sri what exactly you are doing not clear in your question. You want to pass variable from one page to another but don't want to redirect. Then why don't you use jquery-ajax?

Comment: @Rikesh,@ripa : please refer this link for details.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952832/how-can-i-use-concurrent-access-of-mysql-table-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952832/how-can-i-use-concurrent-access-of-mysql-table-in-php @ripa pleasee refer this link for details.

Answer (score 2):

> i'm using header redirect, so cant use get ...

Of course you can. Use:

```
header('Location: test.php?foo=bar');
```

to send the var foo across HTTP redirect as a GET parameter

Also note that a cookie will still be valid after redirect, **if**:

- it is a domain cookie and you are redirecting within the same domain
- it is a path cookie and you are redirecting withing the same path

Comment: OP has said that send data `without using get, post, cookie, session`. So how this answer is useful??

Comment: I've quoted a false assumption and corrected it. I think its useful

Comment: sorry, i cant send variables like this. becoz, if i'm clicking that result link freshly, it ll get refreshed. so get variable ll not be set.

Comment: which *result link*? you told nothing about links in your question

Comment: ok. in ur case , u mentioned like test.php as the link. if i click test.php directly in home page, it'll show the get variable as empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are about to do. (As you not told it clearly). Maybe you'll have to set a proper default value for the variable (in PHP) if the site is clicked in browser directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952832/how-can-i-use-concurrent-access-of-mysql-table-in-php @hek2mgl please refer this link for details.

Answer (score 0):

you can use as....

```
header("location:update_profile.php?msg=record updated")
```

and get it another page as

```
<?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?>
```

or u can use link as

```
<a href='yoursite.php?user=anything......'>click</a>
```

and retrieve it via `Get[]`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this below HTML5 feature will help you, I mean: `sessionStorage`
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Tell me if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session and getmethod to send the value

Get method

```
header("location:update_profile.php?variable=value")
```

and get it another page as

```
<?php echo $_GET['variable']; ?>
```

Setting session

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['variable']='value';
   header("location:update_profile.php");
?>
```

Getting value

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $value=$_SESSION['variable'];
?>
```

Comment: then what about the get method, what is the issue on that?