# How can I use concurrent access of mysql table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, xampp

I have two Php files (a.php, b.php). In a.php I'm retrieving a value from a table and displaying it in PHP and sending it to b.php. In b.php, I'm incrementing that value by 1 and updating it on the table, (but b.php will take more time because of many operations). Now the problem is when performing the operation in b.php, if I clicked a.php for another task, I need to get the incremented value to display in a.php, but it will show only the previous value, because the b.php is not fully executed. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: this is why you must show your code. code says more than a thousand words :-)

Comment: Yes, please show code for a.php and b.php

Answer (score 7):

An `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operation locks the relevant tables [myISAM] or rows [InnoDB] until the operation completes. If a `SELECT` comes in trying to read a locked object it will wait for the operation to complete.

It's worth noting that unless your server is horrendously overloaded, or your `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations number in the many thousands of rows, or both, you will not even notice the wait.

In short: don't even bother worrying about what you've described.

Comment: There can be problems with MyISAM and full table scans using JOINs on non-indexed/keyed columns. Make sure you put indexes on foreign keys (if not marked as actual foreign keys) to avoid this.

Comment: @dlp MyISAM doesn't have FK constraints at all, so there can be no "marking", but it's definitely true that the column types and lengths should match and be indexed as well just as if there were an FK constraint. In this day and age the default table type should be InnoDB, and MyISAM only used if fulltext indexing is needed.

Comment: I did not know about the lack of FK constraints in MyISAM tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a race condition. If script A must wait for all operations of script B to complete in order to assure proper meaning of the count column then you must block script A through table locks (this is true whether the engine is MyIsam or InnoDB). However, if script A does not need to wait for *all* operations of B to finish to give proper meaning to the count column (i.e., only waiting for the increment operation is necessary), then you need to do nothing special.

Having said that, script A is probably not what you need to worry about. **It's more likely that other invocations of script B needing to increment the count column will create your race conditions.** Ensure you are performing your increment through SQL code rather than pulling the value into PHP and then resaving to the database.

Finally, you'll want to make sure you're not creating an aggregate column for no reason. If the count column is merely the number of rows that meet a certain set of criteria, just use the query instead of creating a column that holds the count (aggregate columns/tables should only be used for caching efforts when profiling shows it's necessary and should be clearly named to denote this).

Comment: "Ensure you are performing your increment through SQL code rather than pulling the value into PHP and then resaving to the database." can u kindly explain what is the difference in incrementing directly or through php values? yes i'm incrementing through php values.

Comment: You would simply use a SQL statement to increment the column, i.e., `UPDATE yourtable SET count_col = count_col+1 WHERE id=<someid>`.

Comment: i know update syntax. i'm asking, is there any difference between incrementing through sql query or using php values.

Comment: Using SQL will eliminate the race condition of another process trying to update the column. If you use PHP to do it instead, another process may grab the "stale" count before the first process has a chance to increment and then store the new value.